# How to reset password for BitNami Trac stack?

Tags: passwords, trac

How to reset password for [BitNami](http://bitnami.org/) Trac stack with Windows Vista?

I have a BitNami Trac installation which uses HTTP authentication. How can I reset the forgotten password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to reset the password but maintain the same user you need to execute:

"C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\apache2\bin\htpasswd" -cb "C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\trac\conf\htpasswd" your_old_user new_password

If you also want to change the user name for accessing the application you also will need to give permissions to the new user to your project folder:

"C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\apache2\bin\htpasswd" -cb "C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\trac\conf\htpasswd" new_user new_password

"C:\Program Files\Bitnami Trac Stack\trac\Scripts\trac-admin.exe" "path_to_your_project_folder" permission add new_user TRAC_ADMIN

By default "path_to_your_project_folder" will be in the user documents folder in C:\Users\username\BitNami Trac Stack projects\Project.